# Need help with finding if tangent line goes through origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

the problem is as follows:
a fighter plan can shoot laser beams straight ahead. the fighter plane travels along the path
$$\langle5-t,\, 21 - t^2,\, 3-\frac{t^3}{27}\rangle\ .$$
find a point $t$ where the fighter plane can hit a target at the origin.

i understand you have to find the tangent point at the point $t$. I did that and using the $l(t) = c(t) + t(c't)$ equation for a tangent line i tried to set that equal to zero but am having no luck.

Comment: Don't you think the directional derivative <-1,-2t,-t^2/9>.<1,1,1> = 0 and then find t.  The unit vector (1,1,1) represent the radial vector of a sphere originating from (0,0,0).  I am not sure if you tried this

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  You need the direction of the tangent at a point to be the same as the direction of the point itself from the origin: if you don't see why, draw a diagram.  In algebraic language, ${\bf r}(t)$ should be a scalar times ${\bf r}'(t)$.  See if you can finish it from here.